# gradle processResources seems to be corrupting a font file

Tags: java, gradle, fonts

I have spent several hours on an issue I have come to believe is related to a corrupt file. Basically I am using FlyingSaucer in a spring boot application to generate language compliant pdfs. All my japanese/chinese/russian characters were coming up blank. After thorough research I learned I need to install a good unicode font such as Arial Unicode MS.ttf.

I have downloaded this and installed it on my mac, it seemed good. I put this into my classpath by dropping it into /resources and fetching it using an inputStream. When I fetch it and pass it to BaseFont(pdf generating stuff), it fails saying table 'name' not found. Apparently it is because of a corrupt file(google fu says). I noticed the font file in the build dir and in the src dir have different sizes, so to me they are definitely corrupt. I have tried several other .ttf and they all complain about a name table missing.

I have come to learn that gradle's processResources and Copy method can corrupt files, but I dont understand the fix. I have seem some fixes and copied them but no to avail. I just want to copy a file into the build dir so that my spring boot jar can access the font when generating a pdf.

here is my most recent snippet that I tried with no success(I am new to gradle and this is work related)

```
processResources {
    ////    inputs.properties( version: version.toString() )
////
////    def sourceFiles = source.files
////
////    from(sourceFiles) {
////        include '**/*.properties'
////        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION:
////                                                                            version.toString()])
////    }
////    from(sourceFiles) {
////        exclude '**/*.properties'
////    }
    filesNotMatching("**/*.ttf") {
        it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                releaseVersion: project.version,
                releaseDate: buildDate
        ])
    }
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            LOG_LEVEL_ROOT: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'WARN' : 'INFO',
            LOG_LEVEL_WIRE: buildEnvironment=='mydev' ? 'DEBUG' : 'INFO',
            LOG_LEVEL_CR: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'DEBUG',
            LOG_LEVEL_DB_PARAMS: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'TRACE',
            LOG_LEVEL_DB_QUERY: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'DEBUG' : 'DEBUG',
            LOG_LEVEL_SPRING: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'INFO'
    ])
}
```

according to google the filesnotMatching should make it skip my .ttf file but it still gets copied over and corrupted. I tried adding the .ttf to a different folder and using gradle copy instead of processResources but couldnt get it to work that way(possibly did it wrong).

solution: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/629

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second `filter` is applied to all files. You need to exclude `.ttf` files from that filtering. The easiest way is to move it into `filesNotMatching("**/*.ttf")` block:

```
filesNotMatching("**/*.ttf") {
    it.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            releaseVersion: project.version,
            releaseDate: buildDate
    ])

    it.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            LOG_LEVEL_ROOT: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'WARN' : 'INFO',
            LOG_LEVEL_WIRE: buildEnvironment=='mydev' ? 'DEBUG' : 'INFO',
            LOG_LEVEL_CR: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'DEBUG',
            LOG_LEVEL_DB_PARAMS: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'TRACE',
            LOG_LEVEL_DB_QUERY: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'DEBUG' : 'DEBUG',
            LOG_LEVEL_SPRING: buildEnvironment=='release' ? 'INFO' : 'INFO'
    ])
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked in preventing the copy of the font file. Afterwards I made a copy task and found from here (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/629) a solution to copy without it being corrupt.